# nextTick() not triggering DOM update

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, vuejs3, ionic5

I'm creating a messaging app and I'm having some trouble with scrolling to the bottom of an `ion-content` element when a new message is added to an array. I'm using the `scrollToBottom()` method that comes with `ion-content`, and I'm using the Composition API in Vue 3.

Consider this snippet:

```
setup(props) {
  const replyContent = ref("")
  const messages = ref([])

  // References to ion-content in the template
  const ionContent = ref(null)

  const reply = async () => {
    const message = await replyToThread(props.threadId, replyContent.value).then((message) => message)

    messages.value.push(message)

    nextTick(() => {
      console.log("DOM updated!")

      if (ionContent.value) {
        ionContent.value.$el.scrollToBottom()
      }
    })
  }

  return { replyContent, messages, ionContent, reply }
}
```

`replyToThread()` performs an API call and returns the new message, and `nextTick()` should ensure me that the DOM has been updated so that I can have my way with it. The console does successfully log "DOM updated!", but no scrolling to the bottom happens.

But, and somehow this works every time `nextTick()` doesn't, when I replace the `nextTick()` code block with the following, it works flawlessly:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  if (ionContent.value) {
    ionContent.value.$el.scrollToBottom()
  }
}, 200)
```

I have to set the timeout at around 200 ms, otherwise it doesn't work. But relying on this when something fancy like `nextTick()` should do the trick feels quite dirty. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because `nextTick()` only guarantees that the actual DOM has been updated: it doesn't mean that the browser has actually finished the layout of the page. That is the reason why you need an arbitrary timeout to ensure the scrolling works, because after 200ms the browser is *likely* to be done laying things out based on the updated DOM.

To fix this you will probably need to rely on `window.requestAnimationFrame`:

```
nextTick(() => {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        if (ionContent.value) {
            ionContent.value.$el.scrollToBottom()
        }
    });    
});
```

If this feels like too much nesting for you, you can create a method that returns a promise based on rAF:

```
methods: {
    rAF: function() {
        return new Promise(r => window.requestAnimationFrame(r));
    }
}
```

Then it's a matter of ensuring promises returned by both `nextTick()` and `rAF()` are resolved before scrolling:

```
await nextTick();
await this.rAF();
if (ionContent.value) {
    ionContent.value.$el.scrollToBottom();
}
```